# Why did Moshe need to go up Har Sinai to be told to go down?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, kabbalat-hatorah, parashas-yisro, har-sinai

Exodus 19:20-21

> וַיֵּ֧רֶד  יְהוָ֛ה  עַל־  הַ֥ר  סִינַ֖י  אֶל־  רֹ֣אשׁ  הָהָ֑ר 
>   וַיִּקְרָ֨א  יְהוָ֧ה  לְמֹשֶׁ֛ה  אֶל־  רֹ֥אשׁ  הָהָ֖ר  וַיַּ֥עַל 
>   מֹשֶֽׁה׃  וַיֹּ֤אמֶר  יְהוָה֙  אֶל־  מֹשֶׁ֔ה  רֵ֖ד  הָעֵ֣ד  בָּעָ֑ם 
>   פֶּן־  יֶהֶרְס֤וּ  אֶל־  יְהוָה֙  לִרְא֔וֹת  וְנָפַ֥ל  מִמֶּ֖נּוּ 
>   רָֽב

Why did Moshe need to be told to go up Har Sinai in order to be told to go back down?  Hashem has no trouble speaking to Moshe at the bottom of the mountain, as He spoke to him there in order to call him up.

Comment: Have you ever called someone into your office to tell them to go do something?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't have an office yet, but even when I do, I won't be omnipotent and have the option of direct telepathic communication to all employees at all locations at all times.

Comment: You can ask the same logic on Moshe going to the Ohel Moed to speak to God, or even more generally on the existence of Mikdash/Shuls. Clearly, God tries to work in a normal sort of way and not utilize telepathy. It's helpful to designate spaces of increased spiritual sensitivity, even as we say שויתי ה לנגדי תמיד.

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess what is more bothersome to me is that in our little analogy here, the boss calls someone who is in the boiler room up to the 8th floor to ask them to go down to the boiler room and turn a dial.

Answer (score 1):

Ibn Ezra to [19:20](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/19.20#e0n7) says that Hashem called him up so that the rest of Kelal Yisrael would see that he had come up to the top of the mountain, and realize how great he was:

> וטעם שקראוהו השם – שיראו ישראל גודל מעלת משה, שהגיע אל ראש ההר ששם הכבוד, ודבריו ישמעו מתוך האש שיש שם.‏

I'm not exactly sure what this means, but RDZ Hoffman quotes Ibn Ezra quoting Rasag, that the top of the mountain was a very special spiritual place:

> ודומה הדבר למשכן, אשר אמנם כל-כולו מלא כבוד ה׳ היה, אך למקום התגלות השכינה למשה ולדיבור עמו נקבע ״מעל הכפורת מבין שני הכרבים אשר על-ארון העדת״ (כה, כב) בלבד. וכן גם כאן – כל ההר כולו מקדש היה, וראשו – קדש הקדשים, מקום התגלות השכינה. ומעין זה כבר העיר ראב״ע בביאורו הקצר3: ״אומר הגאון, כי מקום הענן כמו קודש הקדשים״, כלומר ״ענן״ הוא קודש, ״עב הענן״ – קודש קדשים. משמעה של המלה ״עב״ הוא כמו משמע המלה ״ענן״, וגם בישעיה (יט, א) באה המלה ״עב״ כמקום הופעתו ית׳. בקודש יכלו להיכנס גם אחרים, וכפי שנראה להלן, אבל ב״עב הענן״ – בקודש הקדשים זה הורשה להיכנס רק משה בלבד ובכך הוא היה שונה מכל האחרים. הפרדה זו בין קודש וקודש קדשים בהר סיני באה לידי ביטוי ברור כל כך להלן (כד, א ואילך) עד שאין יכול עוד להיות בה כל ספק.‏

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the notion of "going down" is actually referring to the descent from the greatness or level of his position, not from the mountain. See for example [Rashi to Shemos 32:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9893#v=7&showrashi=true) and [Berachos 32a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=32&format=pdf).

Answer (score -1):

Well, I personally think that going up to the mountain has some deeper meaning - it was something that had to be undergone to obtain a message from Hashem, no matter what the message was. I recommend to read this
http://www.studylight.org/com/guz/view.cgi?book=ex&chapter=019
I would say it means that the message was intended for a person with a spiritual strength.
However, I would like to know if Talmud also comments on this.

Answer (score -2):

After Moshe went up some of the sons of Israel satrted to approch the mountain and came dangerously close, so Moshe had to go down again.IMHO